# What date/rank is this Italian uniform?

Tags: identification, uniform, italian

[image: Italian airforce Uniform]

Believed to be from the 1920's from the Turkish or WW1

Any insights into dates, and rank would be great

Answer (score 11):

This is a [1909 model uniform](http://www.pietrigrandeguerra.it/pietri-amedeo/pietri-amedeo-foto-militare/) that is likely from before 1924 when pockets would have been added. Italian uniforms after 1915 bore their rank insignia on sleeves and on the hat, neither of which are present in the image, so we cannot say what this man's rank was.

The collar patch (mostrine) indicated the regiment, but unfortunately the color was a significant component of the symbol and that, of course, is also missing. By the three horizontal stripes over a very dark background, we can narrow him down to one of these infantry regiments:

- Valtellina
- Pisa
- Ancona (most likely, given the shade of the stripes)

Pinerolo and Palermo are possible but less likely as red or blue would not show up so bright.

[image]

However, the collar tabs on your image look very strange, possibly due to the warping of the round glass. Is it possible to get a clearer photo?

[image]